# On convex decomposition of two simple polygons with the smallest number of Steiner points

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, dynamic-programming

Before I go into my problem, here are some definition that might be helpful:

- A diagonal of a polygon P is a segment that joins two vertices of P and remains strictly inside P.
- Steiner point: an extra point added to a vertex set that was not part of the original set, e.g. the vertex 7 in the polygon as shown in Fig. 1.
- A link path is a polyline that is completely inside a polygon. The link path could be a diagonal of a polygon or a collection of line segments. For example, the line segment shown in red dash in Fig. 1 is not completely inside the polygon (intersect with other edge), we add a Steiner point, 7, using the algorithm here such that we have a 2-link path connect vertex 2 and 5.

[image]

We have two simple polygons without holes with the corresponding vertices labeled as 1, 2, …, n.
Let us first look at the simplified problem. As shown in Fig. 2, we have two polygons P and Q. I want to start from the concave polygon P and decompose P into a set of convex sub-polygons using only diagonals without introducing any Steiner points into polygon P. At the same time, we also find the link path in the other polygon Q using the same vertex pair in polygon Q.

For example, we use the diagonal connecting vertex 2 and 5 in P to partition P as shown in Fig. 3. We find the link path that connects vertex 2 and 5 in polygon Q, which introduces a Steiner point 7. (Here, let us just assume we can always find the link path in polygon Q with the smallest number of Steiner points needed)
We want to partition polygon P using diagonals of P while introducing the smallest number of Steiner points into polygon Q. We iteratively decompose P and Q until all the sub-polygon pairs contain a convex polygon. For example, in Fig. 3, sub-polygon pair P_{2345} and Q_{2345} has already contains a convex polygon P_{2345} and we do not need to decompose them anymore. Then, we need to consider sub-polygon pair P_{1256} and Q_{1256} as either of them is convex.

[image]

Here is one example of partitioning polygon P and Q with one Steiner point 7 as shown in Fig. 4.(We add a corresponding point 7 on the diagonal that connects vertex 2 and 5 in P based a linear ratio. The linear ratio is computed by the length of line segment (2,7) in polygon Q overt the total length of the link path that connects vertex 2 and 5 in Q.)

Here are some more cases on convexly decompose polygon P and Q as shown in Fig. 5.

More general problem:
(1) At the beginning, we can start from either polygon P or Q.
(2) During the partition process, we can also starting from the other corresponding sub-poly.
For example, at the beginning, we start from polygon P to decompose P using diagonal that connecting vertex 2 and 4 in P. Then, for sub-polygon pair P_{12456} and Q_{12456}, we could start from Q_{12456} instead of P_{12456} for decomposing. Say, we pick diagonal that connecting vertex 4 and 6 in Q shown in Fig. 6.
I realized that if I want to find the optimum solution there would be exponential combinations. My question is, is there any algorithm can speed it up?

Comment: Too broad a question for StackOverflow?

Comment: @jkdev Maybe I use too many descreption here, which makes it a little complex to understand. Actually, this problem is a litter similar to optimum convex decomposition of a simple polygon. The major difference is that the optimum convex decomposition of a simple polygon intend to minimize the number of diagonal for decomposition. However, I want to mimimize the number of Steiner points. I was wonder if this optimization problem can be solved using dynamic programming or binary search tree?